# VCOV error message

Tags: r, covariance, matrix-inverse

```
Date: 24/04/2017
Version details:
Windows 8.1
RStudio: Version 0.99.473 
R: version 3.2.0
mirt package: version 1.10
```

In the R package mirt (see link below) I created an one dimensional mirt model. (In R-studio and in the original R environment)

(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mirt/mirt.pdf)

What I want and why:

After this I wanted to extract the variance covariance matrix and transform this to the inverse/precision matrix which gives information about covariance between residuals. The inverse matrix tells whether the chosen number of dimension(s) explain (most of) the covariance.

Problem:
The example code for the vcov-method included in the mirt package and the use of vcov in my own model gave the same error message:

example vcov code mirt package (see pdf), performed in RStudio:

```
> x <- mirt(Science, 1, SE=TRUE)
Iteration: 36, Log-Lik: -1608.870, Max-Change: 0.00010
```

Calculating information matrix...

```
> vcov(x)
```

***** error message ******

```
Error in UseMethod("vcov") : 
 no applicable method for 'vcov' applied to an object of class 
 "c('SingleGroupClass', 'AllModelClass')"
```

***** end Error message *****

My own model (just for the info):

```
IRTDASS42_1 <-mirt(data=DASS42_trainingset, model =1, itemtype = 'graded', SE=TRUE)
```

but you need the corresponding dataset to test with this

I found no answers to this in Google, so I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: This looks like it's related to R and not the `mirt` package itself. Maybe try re-installing/upgrading R first to see if the problem persists.